# How can i change the some text between two tags with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom, nokogiri

I have the next tags

```
    <svg><text id="text1" color="red">Hello!</text>
         <text id="text2" color="red">Another text </text></svg>
```

How can i do with Nokogiri to change the content between the tags, so i get

```
 <svg>   <text id="text1" color="red">Goodbye</text>
        <text id="text2" color="red">Another text </text></svg>
```

Is there a method like this??

```
document.at_xpath('//svg/text[@id="text1"]').text="Goodbye"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as below using [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#content=`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-content-3D):

> Set the Node’s content to a Text node containing *string*. The string gets `XML` escaped, not interpreted as markup.

```
document.at_xpath('//svg/text[@id="text1"]').content = "Goodbye"
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting by id would be another solution, possibly more elegant for HTML:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = %q{ 
  <html>
   <body>
    <svg><text id="text1" color="red">Hello!</text>
     <text id="text2" color="red">Another text </text></svg>   </body>
 </html>
}

doc = Nokogiri::XML(html)
hello = doc.at_css('#text1')
hello.content = "Goodbye"

puts doc
```